# How to draw a WebGLTexture into another Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, glsl, shader, webgl

I have a WebGLTexture and I need to draw it into another [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas) or (preferably) [OffscreenCanvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas) by using WebGL calls to run a simple copy/passthrough shader. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of your code, then make an attempt at solving the problem yourself. Where are you stuck specifically? Thanks.

Comment: `texImage2D` accepts a canvas as a data source

Comment: I don't have the canvas, I have the WebGLTexture. Or rather, the canvas has multiple WebGLTextures. It's like a texture in PlayCanvas or Unity WebGL. Everything is drawn to a single canvas, and I need to isolate a single texture into a separate Canvas or OffscreenCanvas.